# Angular material datetime picker change format of displayed date time

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-components

I would like to parse date time just to another format.
It was not an easy to choose complex solution for both date and time picker. Finally I've used `@angular-material-components/datetime-picker@2.0.4` for Angular 9.

I want to present data in format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` however it seems to me that nothing I found supports such solution.

repo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-picker-format-change-yj2pbf

**update**:
**working solution** available under this link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-picker-format-change-ydvzse

Comment: What is wrong with [angular material datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#internationalization) which allows for internationalization?

Comment: It shows only date not time...

Comment: So you solved your problem, didn't you?

Comment: Exactly, I've I left the project here so that others could access this project

Answer (score 0):

MatDatepickerModule is only for dates. Maybe you want to try this (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mat-datetimepicker/core)